# Get argument of tkinter instance in other module

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I would like to create a program which does the following thing via a GUI:

1.) Choose a directory in which some new directories will be created

2.) give those new directories names by using an entry widget.

Since the program is rather going to be large, I would like to split up my code into several modules which causes me some problems

What I have done so far is the following thing:

I have a "main"-program using.py

```
import os, sys
import Tkinter

import tkFileDialog
#import own modules
import Gui

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()


directory='some path'


tempdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=directory, 
     title='Please choose a location for your directory')

n2=Gui.DirectoryCreator()
n2.mainloop()
```

The module Gui looks like this

```
import Tkinter as tk
class DirectoryCreator(tk.Tk):
    text=''
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.label=tk.Label(self, text='Enter the name of the directory')
            self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
            self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Name Of Folder",width=15, command=self.on_button)
            self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.button.grid(row=0,column=2)
            self.entry.grid(row=0,column=1)

        def on_button(self):
            text= self.entry.get()
            self.quit()
```

Now, the point is that I somehow need to get the value of the string 'text' in the module using.py. If I try something like n2.text, the streing n2.text is simply empty, e.g. n2.text="". How can I get this string?

Comment: What happens when you try getting `n2.text`? Is there an error? Does it return `""`? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it returns n2.text="". What does not work? I simply don't know how to access the entry from the entry widget in using.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `on_button`, use `self.text = self.entry.get()`. Just using `text` is like declaring a new variable instead of using the `text` already bound to the `DirectoryCreator` instance.

```
def on_button(self):
    self.text= self.entry.get()
    self.quit()
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But I am a little surprised that it actually works. How can I define a variable self.text? Doesn't self always point to an instance of a Tkinter module? If so, why is it possible to declare a string belonging to this instance? I wouldn't have expected that a Tkinter object can possess a string in a definition? Besides that, this only works if I put the line self.text after the __init__ statement? Why so? If I put it in front, I get stuck in the mainloop and nothing happens

Comment: `self` is referring to your subclass of `tk.Tk`. When you say `self.text = ""`, all you're doing is setting a new attribute `text` on your instance. It's the same way you are defining `self.entry = tk.Entry()`. `self.text` is just the pointer pointing to the string. If you change it to point to anything else, it will still be valid. You can assign `self.text` to any data type. It doesn't pick and choose what type of data it can point to.

Comment: Also, only the second paragraph of my answer is really what fixed it. The first paragraph is only applicable for mutable data types (strings are immutable), so I'll remove that from my answer since it's not necessary here. You only have to define an attribute inside the `__init__` for things like `list`s and `dict`s. You can define text the way you did in your question.

Comment: And what do you mean if you put it after the `__init__` statement? Are you talking about the `tk.Tk.__init__(self)` expression?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It made it difference when I put I before or after this statement. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help;)

Comment: You should always call the superclass's `__init__` before running your own code because it sets up everything you need for it to be a full instance of that superclass. I'm not quite sure in your case, but there's probably something in the `tk.Tk.__init__` that's screwing it up for you. And no problem :)